# Prevent post back on enter key in telerik MVC dll grid

Tags: telerik-mvc

I want to prevent Post back on Enter key press in telerik MVC dll grid.
is there any way to do this.
please suggest.
thanks

Answer (score 0):

What did you try to prevent the event from bubbling ? I would suggest something like this:

```
    $(function(){
        $('.t-grid').data().tGrid.element.on('keydown',function(e){
          if(e.keyCode==13){
                e.stopImmediatePropagation();
         }
        })
    })
```

Comment: Hi @Petur Subev, thanks for the answer, but it do't work for me.